# Marshal not @XmlRootElement with JAXB to String

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, wsdl2java, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I need to marshal one `JAXB` generated object to `String`. The problem is that it does not have an `@XmlRootElement` annotation. It is not a root element. The element in `XSD` looks like this:

```
  <xs:complexType name="CompletedAssessmentInstance">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="tns:AssessmentInstance">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CompletionDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CustomResultsXML" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="NormedScores" nillable="true" type="tns:NormedScores"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RawScore" type="xs:decimal"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TimeTaken" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="CompletedAssessmentInstance" nillable="true" type="tns:CompletedAssessmentInstance"/>
```

`tns` prefix points to this name space: x`mlns:tns="http://www.cubiksonline.com/2009/08/AssessmentProvider"`

I found out that I can do this to marshal not `XML` root elements with `JAXB`:

```
public static String completedAssessmentInstanceToString(CompletedAssessmentInstance assessmentInstance)
        throws AssessmentException {
    try {
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

        QName qname = new QName(
                "http://www.cubiksonline.com/2009/08/AssessmentProvider",
                "CompletedAssessmentInstance");

        JAXBElement<CompletedAssessmentInstance> rootElement = new JAXBElement<CompletedAssessmentInstance>(
                qname,
                CompletedAssessmentInstance.class,
                assessmentInstance);

        marshaller.marshal(rootElement, writer);

        return writer.toString();
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("JAXB Exception occurred.", ex);
        throw new AssessmentException(RequestStatusValue.InvalidProjectConfiguration,
                "Unable to marshal the CompletedAssessmentInstance data: " + assessmentInstance, ex);
    }
}
```

I am initializing my `JAXB` context like this:

```
private static JAXBContext jc = createJaxbContext();

private static JAXBContext createJaxbContext() {
    try {
        ClassLoader cl = com.cubiksonline._2009._08.assessmentprovider.ObjectFactory.class.getClassLoader();
        return JAXBContext.newInstance("com.cubiksonline._2009._08.assessmentprovider", cl);
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to create JAXB context: ", ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

This package: `com.cubiksonline._2009._08.assessmentprovider` is the package where there are all `JAXB` generated classes including and `CompletedAssessmentInstance`. The problem is when the `marshaller.marshal(rootElement, writer);` is invoked I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: com.cubiksonline._2009._08.assessmentprovider.CompletedAssessmentInstance is not known to this context]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:318)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:244)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:95)
    at com.groupgti.esb.assessments.cubiks.CubiksFactory.completedAssessmentInstanceToString(CubiksFactory.java:272)[647:com.groupgti.esb.online.tests.cubiks:1.2.0.SNAPSHOT]
    ... 40 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: com.cubiksonline._2009._08.assessmentprovider.CompletedAssessmentInstance is not known to this context
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:246)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:261)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:144)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:316)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:494)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:315)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: com.cubiksonline._2009._08.assessmentprovider.CompletedAssessmentInstance is not known to this context
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:625)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:141)
    ... 49 more
```

Does anyone know where might the problem?

Comment: Since you are using the JAXB RI, the `toString()` on its implementation of `JAXBContext` will output all the mapped classes.  Could you check that to make sure that `com.cubiksonline._2009._08.assessmentprovider.CompletedAssessmentInstance` is included.  Also since JAXB is a spec (JSR-222) you could try another implementation such as EclipseLink MOXy (I'm the MOXy lead) to see if this is just a bug in the JAXB RI.

Comment: It is strange because when I do toString on JAXBContext it just lists 9 classes, in this package there are about 50 classes and this class com.cubiksonline._2009._08.assessmentprovider.CompletedAssessmentInstance is not included. I have already found the solution. I had to initialize JAXB context like that:

JAXBContext.newInstance(CompletedAssessmentInstance.class)

But still I can't understand why JAXB does not loads all the classes from specified package.

Comment: You may have found a bug in the JAXB RI.  You could try a newer version or alternate implementation of JAXB (JSR-222) to confirm.

Comment: I am using cxf-codegen-plugin:2.6.0, if I change the version to cxf-codegen-plugin:2.4.2 everything works, I see all the classes coming from JAXBContext. But I've looked at dependencies tree and I see that they both uses Group ID: com.sun.xml.bind Artifact ID: jaxb-impl Version: 2.1.13. This is the same versions.

Comment: Ok, so it appears to be a bug in the `cxf-codegen-plugin` and not with the JAXB reference implementation.  I would recommend filing a bug with CXF.

Comment: Yeah, it must be something wrong with cxf-codegen-plugin, I'll try to find out what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround for this issue. I had to create `JAXBContext` for the specific class like this:

```
private static JAXBContext createJaxbContext() {
    try {
        return JAXBContext.newInstance(CompletedAssessmentInstance.class);
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to create JAXB context: ", ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

This does not solves the problem, it's just workaround. I was using `cxf-codegen-plugin:2.6.0` to generated classes from `WSDL` file, what I noticed was that if I change the version to `cxf-codegen-plugin:2.4.2` everything works just fine using the class loader. If I will find the problem I will post the solution here.